# Why do I keep getting the error message "no member named "TokenType" in 'Token' '"?

Tags: c++, file, header, include

I am using c++ to make a lexical analyzer for one of my classes and am having a problem with the contents of my header file being included in my source files. I #include the header file into my source files but it keeps saying that it can't find the members included.

The header file is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum TokenType {
    ID,         // identifier
    STR,        // string
    INT,        // integer constant
    PLUS,       // the + operator
    STAR,       // the * operator
    LEFTSQ,     // the [
    RIGHTSQ,    // the ]
    PRINT,      // print keyword
    SET,        // set keyword
    SC,     // semicolon
    LPAREN,     // The (
    RPAREN,     // the )
    DONE,       // finished!
    ERR,        // an unrecoverable error
};

class Token {
private:
    TokenType   tok;
    std::string lexeme;

public:
    Token() : tok(ERR), lexeme("") {}
    Token(TokenType t, std::string s) : tok(t), lexeme(s) {}

    TokenType   getTok() const      { return tok; }
    std::string getLexeme() const   { return lexeme; }

    friend bool operator==(const Token& left, const Token& right) {
        return left.tok == right.tok;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Token& t);
};

extern  int linenum;
extern  Token   getToken(std::istream* instream);
```

While I have this part of code from one of the files that has multiple errors:

```
 map<Token::TokenType,int> tokenCount;
    map<string,int> lexemeCount;
    Token t;

    while( (t = getTok(br)) != Token::TokenType::DONE && t !=Token::TokenType::ERR ) {
        tokenCount[t.getType()]++;
        if( t == Token::TokenType::VAR
           || t == Token::TokenType::SCONST
           || t == Token::TokenType::ICONST ) {
            lexemeCount[t.getLexeme()]++;
        }
```

I am sure this is an easy fix but I'm not sure how to fix this. I been trying to fix it for a couple of days now and can't figure it out.

Comment: But you don't have such member in `Token`!!! Aside from a bunch of member functions the only members you declared in in your  `Token` are `tok` and `lexeme`. Why are you trying to access `Token::TokenType`?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is exactly what the debugger is telling you. TokenType is not a member of the class Token, so you can't say Token::TokenType. You just need to refer to it as TokenType.

Comment: "Your error is exactly what the debugger is telling you." The code won;t reach the debugger. Did you mean 'compiler'?

Comment: I guess you are right, this is a compiler error, and it's coming from the compiler. But that isn't the point of my comment, the question wasn't "where is this error coming from?", so I would say that is a negligible inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `TokenType` outside of `Token`, so there's no identifier named `TokenType` defined inside of `Token`, therefore `Token::TokenType` isn't defined.

You have two obvious choices. Either define `TokenType` inside of `Token`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Token {

    enum TokenType {
        ID,         // identifier
        // ...
        ERR,        // an unrecoverable error
    };

// ...    
};
```

... or else use the name TokenType`without the`Token::`on the front. If you want to qualify the name with`TokenType`, use an`enum class`:

```
enum class TokenType {
    ID,         // identifier
    // ...
    ERR,        // an unrecoverable error
};

map<TokenType, int> tokenCount;
map<string, int> lexemeCount;
Token t;

while ((t = getTok(br)) != TokenType::DONE && t != TokenType::ERR) {
    tokenCount[t.getType()]++;
    if (t == TokenType::VAR
        || t == TokenType::SCONST
        || t == TokenType::ICONST) {
        lexemeCount[t.getLexeme()]++;
    }
```

You can, of course, combine the type, and define `TokenType` as an `enum class` inside of the `Token` class as well (though some would consider this a bit over-protective, so to speak).